# Ubuntu 10.04: Restrict LDAP Access by Group (OpenDirectory on Mac OS X Server)

Tags: linux, authentication, mac-osx-server, opendirectory, ubuntu-10.04

In a nutshell, I want to authenticate users of a Ubuntu 10.04 Server against a Mac OS X Server's OpenDirectory LDAP but **ONLY allow them access if they are a member of a group** on the LDAP side.

Using some guides and previous experience, I am able to get it to get the authentication part working - that part's simple:

> $ sudo apt-get install libpam-ldap libnss-ldap nss-updatedb

and enter the LDAP URI, search base, etc as prompted.

At that point, I'm able to see the users / groups on the OpenDirectory LDAP server

> # getent passwd
>
> # getent group

And I can even ssh to the box as ANY of the users

The problem is -- I can't figure out how to restrict access to only a certain group of users (e.g. testssh)

[Using this guide](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2006/09/08/ldap-based-access-control/), I made the following changes to the /etc/ldap.conf file:

> pam_groupdn cn=testssh,cn=groups,dc=myserver,dc=mycompany,dc=net
>
> pam_member_attribute uniquemember

Hopefully someone has solved this issue and I am just missing something obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `/etc/security/access.conf`.  Changes to this file will affect anything that uses pam and the pam_access module, and permits you to restrict login by group membership.

You can check group membership with '`getent group <group name>`'

Comment: Thank you VERY much -- after I uncommented a line in /etc/pam.d/sshd - account  required     pam_access.so -- this does let me restrict by name and I see how it's supposed to work with @netgroup -- but something must be wrong with the rest of the pam config -- because even though 'getent group' shows the user as a member of the ldap group (or even local group) they can't login, unless explicitly allowed by username. -- I'll test some more!

Answer (score 0):

I've no Mac but this is how I do and I think you can do the same.

put on your sshd_config on the mac:

```
AllowGroups testssh
```

it will allow only the users in testssh LDAP group

Comment: This assumes PAM even allows you to get as far as SSH.